# Cannot set property of undefined of a child object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting an "cannot set property of addressline_1 of undefined  when I trying assign a value for my addressline_1 which is a child object of the parent object physical. Appreciate if any one can tell me how I can resolve this problem? Thank you in advance.

```
$scope.editCompany = function(){
  $scope.submitCompany =[{phone:[]}]; 
  $scope.submitCompany[0].name = "Some Company";
  $scope.submitCompany[0].email = "company@example.com";
  $scope.submitCompany[0].is_active = "TRUE";
  $scope.submitCompany[0].physical.addressline_1 = "77 Example rd";
}
```

I've also tried the following with no luck.

```
$scope.editCompany = function(){
  $scope.submitCompany =[{phone:[]},{physical:{addressline_1:"",addressline_2:"",addressline_3:"",addressline_4:"",city:"", region:"",country:"", post_code:""}}]; 
  $scope.submitCompany[0].name = "Some Company";
  $scope.submitCompany[0].email = "company@example.com";
  $scope.submitCompany[0].is_active = "TRUE";
  $scope.submitCompany[0].physical.addressline_1 = "77 Example rd";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `physical` object first before trying to set its properties:

```
$scope.editCompany = function(){
  $scope.submitCompany =[{phone:[]}]; 
  $scope.submitCompany[0].name = "Some Company";
  $scope.submitCompany[0].email = "company@example.com";
  $scope.submitCompany[0].is_active = "TRUE";
  $scope.submitCompany[0].physical = {};
  $scope.submitCompany[0].physical.addressline_1 = "77 Example rd";
};
```

or cleaner syntax of the same:

```
$scope.editCompany = function () {
    $scope.submitCompany = [{
        phone: [],
        name: "Some Company",
        email: "company@example.com",
        is_active: "TRUE",
        physical: {
            addressline_1: "77 Example rd"
        }
    }];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with assigning an object to the `physical` property before setting properties, but you put it at `$scope.submitCompany[1].physical` instead of `$scope.submitCompany[0].physical`.

Put the `physical` property in the same object as the `phone` property:

```
$scope.editCompany = function(){
  $scope.submitCompany = [ { phone: [], physical: {} } ]; 
  $scope.submitCompany[0].name = "Some Company";
  $scope.submitCompany[0].email = "company@example.com";
  $scope.submitCompany[0].is_active = "TRUE";
  $scope.submitCompany[0].physical.addressline_1 = "77 Example rd";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do small change..

```
$scope.editCompany = function(){
  $scope.submitCompany =[{phone:[]},{physical:{addressline_1:"",addressline_2:"",addressline_3:"",addressline_4:"",city:"", region:"",country:"", post_code:""}}]; 
 ....
  $scope.submitCompany[1].physical.addressline_1 = "77 Example rd"; // instead $scope.submitCompany[0].physical.addressline_1
}
```